# Problems connecting to rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I'm working at getting a very basic ruby/rails environment up and running, and I am presently unable to connect to it.

I'm working on a Macbook (updates current), and I've got an Ubuntu VM running that I'm using as my test server.

I have port-forwarding set up for connecting with the VM (hypervisor = VirtualBox)

- 8083 to 80 (http)
- 9307 to 3306 (mysql)
- 2223 to 22 (ssh)
- 3010 to 3000 (WEBrick)

[VM Port-Forwarding Setup Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQu3K.png)

I have not setup a firewall on the server

Using this, I can ssh in, and I can hit "non-rails" sites just fine via Apache.  What I can't do is get a basic "hello-world" screen up for the rails environment.  I CAN get there if I cut out the VM and start WEBrick ("rails s") directly from the Mac environment and then go to localhost's port 3000, but when I attempt the same thing on the VM and then try to hit port 3010 the same way, I get back a "no data received" response.

WEBrick appears to be running just fine

```
myserver$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2016-02-08 09:01:30] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-02-08 09:01:30] INFO  ruby 2.1.5 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
[2016-02-08 09:01:30] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3756 port=3000
```

Turning Apache on/off does not change anything beyond changing the accessibility of the content served by Apache.

I've tried monitoring "log/development.log" in my rails application, and I've also poked around to see if I noticed any clues in any of the various log files under "/var/log", but nothing's jumping out at me.

I am not doing anything fancy here. I just want to get to the "Welcome Aboard!" screen for rails. I thought that getting started would be as simple as setting up the port-forwarding, creating the rails-application, and hitting it from my browser; it's been a few hours now and I'm getting nowhere with this. Apologies if this has a super easy solution that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: Do you get a response if you open a shell on the VM and run `curl http://localhost:3000/`? If yes than the issue is purely your port forwarding.

Comment: Also what sort of hypervisor are you using? Paralells, Virtualbox, Fusion or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
curl http://localhost:3000 works, so the server is (as expected) running.
I'm using VirtualBox

Comment: I've altered the original post to show the VM setup.  So the server is definitely working, because the curl command returns what we expect.  I'm not sure why the port-forwarding is working just fine for everything else that I've set up and not for this particular case...

Comment: I actually haven't used virtualbox that much but what happens if you try another port on the host like `3000 -> 3030`?

Comment: I changed it to a couple of different configs (3030 among them).  No dice.  Same result

Comment: Also attempted a straight 3000 -> 3000 forwarding... no luck.

Comment: Perhaps it's a users/permissions issue?  I recall that I had to set up access for the "vboxsf" group, and to add the apache user to that group when I was setting up apache access.  Do I need to do something similar here?